# GitBox Pull Failed with changes not present

Tags: git, gitbox

I am new to Git and have taken the ambitious step of having several branches - the code base I inherited is massive.  I am 100% positive I have commited all changes, now I am getting the following message:

> Pull Failed - Please commit your changes and try again.

Any advice what to do on this?  I have tried switching between branches on both ends with no success:

Comment: The message was "Pull Failed" - Please commit your changes and try again.

I did not realize that it would be sized down that small, sorry.

Comment: (this same message applies when I try to push)

Comment: What does git status say?

Comment: `git status` should show you the files that git considers to be uncommitted.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, thanks - in fact I was working with GitBox and Therefore didn't see everything.  Started doing things from Mac terminal and was finally able to resolve.  Instructions from terminal are more helpful than what GitBox gives you

Comment: I'm glad :-) graphical interfaces are for noobs anyway